# Update data model when csv files get extended by extra columns

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a data model in Power BI desktop that was loaded from a couple of csv and Excel files. The csv files were exports from a database. Afer I started modeling the relationships between the tables, establishing a DAX calendar and a few measures, we received some updated versions of the .csv files which are now extended by a few extra columns.

I used Python to bring the columns into the original order and tried "update from data sources". After bringing the columns into the original order, the import now runs without issues. But the problem is that the new columns are not recognized and they do not show up in the tables. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the import works like powerquery, locate the **,columns=6,** section of the first row of code, and remove that

so

```
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\temp2\data.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=6, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
```

becomes

```
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\temp2\data.csv"),[Delimiter=",",  Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this. Any chance that I may also skip the reordering of columns with Python? I mean updating the data model from the new csc files, independent of the previous column ordering?

Comment: I don't know why the ordering of the columns should matter when bringing them in. Try without

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! You helped me a lot. And now it also works without a prior reordering of the columns. I already asked in the Microsoft Power BI forum; but there no-one could help. ONE LAST THING THOUGH: Could you please explain, WHY this does the trick? In my case "columns=14" correctly represented the number of columns in the updated file. Thus, not sure why this apparently correct setting created the problem. Maybe I am also confused about the time ordering of the steps. The preview table was correct, the M syntax contained the right number of columns, but less columns were imported.

Comment: Sorry. No insights into that. If there were 14 columns, then 14 should have been imported